# does selenium 2.24 supports windows 2012?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have to work on  Amazon EC2 server. Client has installed windows 2012 server. 
I have to automate and execute all test cases on that server only.
My question is that does Selenium 2.24 supports windows 2012 ? Even which version of version are supported on windows 2012 for selenium 2.24 ?
Also please share url of selenium supported browser and os

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can be run on any os that supports java.

[Platforms & browsers](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html)